# Converting report from odoo 11 to odoo 12

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml, odoo-11, odoo-12

I am trying to convert report from odoo 11 to odoo 12, i have ran through the code trying to see this "list" 
with the problem but i cant seem to note it.

**returned data from report.py**

```
 return {
     'doc_ids': partner_ids,
     'doc_model': 'res.partner',
     'docs': self.env['res.partner'].browse(partner_ids),
     'Amount_Due': amount_due,
     'Lines': lines_to_display,
     'Buckets': buckets_to_display,
     'Currencies': currency_to_display,
     'Show_Buckets': data['show_aging_buckets'],
     'Filter_non_due_partners': data['filter_non_due_partners'],
     'Date_end': date_end_display,
     'Date': today_display,
     'account_type': account_type,
  }
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
body = bytearray().join([lxml.html.tostring(c) for c in body_parent.getchildren()])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getchildren'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the problem is in your report template, not in the report data. You did not provide the template code you are using in your report so it is hard to diagnose more details about the reason. Check that your template is correctly set. You can find more info from the Odoo report reference at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/reports.html#report-template. If the problem persists, please complete your question with the template and other relevant code.